# GridFS Java Can't Connect

Tags: java, mongodb, android-studio, gridfs

I am trying to connect to my mongoDB from my android studio app. However, I'm getting hold when connecting the app waits for 30 seconds and toast and long error message stating it was still trying to connect but it terminated it self.

This is my code:

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user, database, password);
MongoClientOptions.Builder o = MongoClientOptions.builder().connectTimeout(3000);
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("188.166.149.168", 27017),
Arrays.asList(credential), o.build() );
DB db =mongo.getDB("notifellow");
GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(db);
```

Comment: Does only GridFS fail? Can you access a collection in your database? What is the error - please edit your question and add the stacktrace.

Comment: i debugged to see that gridFS fails....

Comment: You need to provide the stacktrace of the error, otherwise no one will be able to help you.